# Minesweeper in React -- design for state management/data flow

Tags: react.js, minesweeper

I've pasted here a basic implementation I've done of a Minesweeper game. This is not the full functionality, only the populating/revealing of squares. The idea is that the user inputs `rows,cols,list-of-bombs` as a string, and the game generates a board of the input dimensions, with bombs at the input indices.

I'm specifically wondering about maintaining the state of all these cells. I originally stored the board and visibility list as 2d arrays, but that didn't seem right.

I would really like to learn if my strategy for state management was good. I had a similar question on a take home for a trading desk role at a HFT firm, and I failed, so I'm trying to see if I can learn from my experience.

I'm also wondering why my `<Cell />` components keep rerendering each time a cell is toggled.

```
// LIB
const generateMap = <vals = number | boolean,>(
  rows: number,
  cols: number,
  defVal: vals
) => range(rows * cols).reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr]: defVal }), {});

const range = (num: number) => {
  const res = [];
  let count = 0;
  while (count < num) {
    res.push(count++);
  }
  return res;
};

const addBombs = (values: Record<string, number>, bombs: string[]) => ({
  ...values,
  ...bombs.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr]: -1 }), {}),
});

const addValues = (
  values: Record<string, number>,
  row: number,
  col: number
) => {
  const getCount = (key: number) => (values[key] == -1 ? 1 : 0);

  for (const key in values) {
    if (values[key] == -1) {
      continue;
    }
    const keyNum = Number(key);
    const rowCount = Math.floor(keyNum / row);
    const colCount = keyNum % col;

    const left = colCount > 0 ? getCount(keyNum - 1) : 0;
    const right = colCount < col - 1 ? getCount(keyNum + 1) : 0;
    const up = rowCount > 0 ? getCount(keyNum - col) : 0;
    const down = rowCount < row - 1 ? getCount(keyNum + col) : 0;
    const topLeft =
      colCount > 0 && rowCount > 0 ? getCount(keyNum - col - 1) : 0;
    const topRight =
      colCount < col - 1 && rowCount > 0 ? getCount(keyNum - col + 1) : 0;
    const downLeft =
      colCount > 0 && rowCount < row - 1 ? getCount(keyNum + col - 1) : 0;
    const downRight =
      colCount < col - 1 && rowCount < row - 1 ? getCount(keyNum + col + 1) : 0;

    values[key] =
      left + right + up + down + topLeft + topRight + downLeft + downRight;
  }
  return values;
};



// COMPONENTS
const Input = ({ handlePlay }: { handlePlay: (val: string) => void }) => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        marginBottom: 20,
      }}
    >
      <input type="text" value={val} onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => handlePlay(val)}>Play</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Cell = React.memo(
  ({
    visible,
    value,
    handleClick,
  }: {
    visible: boolean;
    value: number;
    handleClick: () => void;
  }) => {
    console.log('cell rendering')
    return (
      <div
        onClick={() => handleClick()}
        style={{
          padding: 10,
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          width: "30px",
          height: "30px",
          border: "1px solid grey",
          backgroundColor: visible ? "white" : "lightgrey",
        }}
      >
        {visible && (value > -1 ? value : "")}
      </div>
    );
  }
);

const Grid = ({
  seen,
  values,
  rows,
  cols,
  handleCellClick,
}: {
  seen: Record<string, boolean>;
  values: Record<string, number>;
  rows: number;
  cols: number;
  handleCellClick: (key: string) => void;
}) => {
  const key = (row: number, col: number) => (row * cols + col).toString();

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      {range(rows).map((r) => (
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
          }}
        >
          {range(cols).map((c) => (
            <Cell
              key={key(r, c)}
              handleClick={() => handleCellClick(key(r, c))}
              value={values[key(r, c)]}
              visible={seen[key(r, c)]}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState<Record<string, number>>({});
  const [seen, setSeen] = useState<Record<string, boolean>>({});
  const [[rows, cols], setRowCol] = useState<number[]>([]);

  const handlePlay = (val: string) => {
    const [row, col, ...bombs] = val.split(",");

    const valuesMap = generateMap(Number(row), Number(col), 0);
    const seenMap = generateMap(Number(row), Number(col), false);

    setValues(addValues(addBombs(valuesMap, bombs), Number(row), Number(col)));
    setSeen(seenMap);
    setRowCol([Number(row), Number(col)]);
  };

  const handleCellClick = useCallback(
    (key: string) => {
      setSeen({
        ...seen,
        [key]: true,
      });
    },
    [seen]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Input handlePlay={handlePlay} />
      <Grid
        rows={rows}
        cols={cols}
        seen={seen}
        values={values}
        handleCellClick={handleCellClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it shouldn't ultimately matter how you store it underneath.  There's some advantage for keeping everything in a 1D array for React in making new references quickly.

The important thing is to abstract the manipulation of state so it doesn't matter and put a boundary between game logic and state.  I'd keep the game logic around the idea row/col pairs a long as I absolutely could and only start dealing with the implementation when I had to.  You're doing this earlier than necessary in `addValues` when you could theoretically push it off to `getCount` with a change of signature.

I think you're on the right track with the `addValues` interface (pass in the array, give it a column and number), but the key as a string is definitely awkward.  You're going to have unique values from `row * cols + col`, so I'd just use a simple array and index it that way.

I'd really consider making a new `Values` class which gets your `generateMap` as the constructor, remembers the sizes, and then holds the `values` as an array.  It gets instantiated each render with the `values` from the state.  The `values` later can be retrieved via a getter which returns a copy you can then feed into your `setValues` state after manipulation.  I'd expect introducing a class doesn't hurt performance, but do keep it in mind.

In any scenario, you can have a simpler `addValues` which double loops over `rows` and `cols` (or `this.rows`, `this.cols` if using a class).  `getCount` can take the row/col pair and calculate the index via `row * this.ncols + col` rather than the string -> number -> floor -> juggle keyNum math.  I think this should make the calculation of the values around the cell more readable.

Also, you can replace your `range` function with something like

```
[...Array(num).keys()]
```

Answer (score 2):

The code seems well formatted and the variables are generally well chosen. There are too many literals in there to my liking and obviously these overly large constructs are not very legible for those that are not used to that.

Somebody needs to be pretty deep into function programming to understand what is going on at all.

Constructs such as:

```
const addBombs = (values: Record<string, number>, bombs: string[]) => ({
  ...values,
  ...bombs.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr]: -1 }), {}),
});
```

blows my mind. It must be smart, as I'm not sure I understand what is going on at all. Considering that it simply puts the bombs in place I'm wondering when the sanity of procedural programming went out of the window.

---

The fact that it uses stringified position in an one-dimensional array rather to use a position muddles the water, but I guess that comes with the restrictions build into JavaScript & TypeScript. One way around it would be to create an object that can be serialized and deserialized, but that would increase the code size and it would still require explicit calls to the serialization method. Then again, if you'd serialize to "(<x>, <y>)" then this would undoubtedly help with e.g. debugging.

---

The fact that *apparently* `-1` represents a bomb must be retrieved from the code. There are a lot of `const` but no constant to indicate that `-1` represents a bomb. This is relatively simple to do, but it does obscure code more than it should as these kind of readability issues add up (if not multiply).

---

The part that calculates the number of bombs contains a lot of inline calculations that are hard to understand. I'd use a different abstraction using positions and directions instead.

I've asked ChatGPT to create something for me and it came up with the following:

```
const Directions = {
  Left: [-1, 0] as const,
  Down: [0, -1] as const,
  Right: [1, 0] as const,
  Up: [0, 1] as const,
  // Add any other directions you need
} as const;

// Example of how to use these directions
type Direction = typeof Directions[keyof typeof Directions];

function neighbor(position: [number, number], direction: Direction): [number, number] {
  return [position[0] + direction[0], position[1] + direction[1]];
}

// Example usage
const startPosition: [number, number] = [5, 5];
const newPosition = neighbor(startPosition, Directions.Left); // This would be [4, 5]
```

Of course that still requires some calculations to see if a position is actually on the board, but that's very easy to do as well.

---

Keys are calculated as strings. This is OK, as TypeScript does always treat the keys within a `Record` as a symbol or key. Still, it might be a better idea to configure a record as `<number, number>` to more clearly convey what it is for. Or use a string that conveys a position more clearly as mentioned earlier.

---

I see many separate calls to `getCount` and `key(r, c)` in the code. It is good that these are separate functions. That said, when I'm writing code I do try to make sure that I call methods as few times as possible. That's certainly possible for `getCount` if e.g. you're iterating through neighbors of a cell.

For `key` this may be a bit harder to do because you're already in a lambda, but it is possible:

```
// Capture the output of the key function in a variable
const keyValue = key(r, c);
return (
  <Cell
    key={keyValue}
    handleClick={() => handleCellClick(keyValue)}
    value={values[keyValue]}
    visible={seen[keyValue]}
  />
);
```

Comment: PS When I started typing this there were no answers yet. I wanted to indicate that although the code is well structured I still think that there are ways to make it more readable. Then again, as mentioned multiple times, this is not my (main) language.